# What's an example of a small custom DSL for internet advertising?

Tags: dsl

I'm just learning about DSLs and I'm trying to put them in a context I can understand.

Let's say we're talking about internet advertising, for example - since that's a field I would like to work in - what's an example of a small custom DSL you might build?

Also, what are some of the high level technical steps you would need to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Domain specific languages are, by definition, a language designed for use by the domain experts.

The topic is quite large, and can be segmented by:

- internal or external - is it part of a host language which programmers write, or standalone.
- imperative or declarative - do you dictate the flow of a "program", or are you writing down properties that need be fulfilled.
- audience - is this to be written by programmers or non-programmers

A large subset of DSLs (including the one below) can be described as rules which are evaluated all at once by a rules or inference engine.

For the domain of internet advertising, you may want to come up with a set of business rules which govern which ads are shown on a given page.

```
if page.popularity is high then use ads of account[valuable]

if page.topic is not NSFW then use ads of topic[not NSFW]

if browser does not support flash then use ads of capability[javascript]
```

In this particular case, a clean, popular page would get the ads from the best paying account, and safe for work.

If this is an approach which has resonance for you, you may want to integrate an existing Rules Engine. This is particularly sage if the end-users are not developers, as you will need to provide a certain amount of tooling as well as the DSL.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using DSL Tools for VS2005 for the last year.

In order to learn it, you ought to read 
"Domain-Specific Development with Visual Studio DSL Tools" by
Steve Cook, Gareth Jones, Stuart Kent and Alan Cameron Wills.

This should be your entry point and it covers every aspect about the technology including some advanced topics.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the game, but...

Google has such DSLs that specific the ads a google advertiser can run.  It consists of the usual Google searches (broad match [unquoted text], phrase match [a quoted character sequence], and exact match [a character sequence in brackets]) along with "negative keywords" which are Google searches used to eliminate a match.   It is entered through a set of forms and so it doesn't look like programming, but what is entered is ultimately some pretty concise text strings.    It isn't a very clever DSL IMHO (I actually had to use it, I wish it included regular expressions at the low end and natural language parses at the high end) but it is very real and used by millions of "non-programmers".

There are two steps to implementing a DSL: parsing it (to understand what it says) and mechanizing its meaning.  Parsing is pretty well understood; see any of the questions on parsing floating around Stack Overflow.  Mechanizing is lot harder; what we think of as "Google" *is* largely the mechanization of that DSL.